# Automate CasperJS every hour from server and get updated if FAIL occurs

Tags: automation, casperjs, ui-testing

First time running with CasperJS. My tests work locally. I've got a script to run:

`casper test check-add-to-cart.js`

Now how can I get this to run hourly on a Modulus/DigitalOcean server, and update team if it fails? Maybe, Slack, but that could be a whole other question/google-search.

Answer (score 1):

A popular way to do that is to set up your own CI server (or use a hosted version of the same), such as Jenkins:

https://jenkins.io/

https://circleci.com/ and https://drone.io/ are alternate options, and there are others.

Any CI server should give you the ability to email a list of recipients when your test fails - and most have Slack integration these days as well.

Comment: I use casperjs and Team City. CI server is the way to go